# Alternating sum of primes.

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Do we know the sum, 
$$\sum_p \frac{\chi\left(p\right)}{p}\textrm{?}$$
for $\chi\left(n\right)$ being $1$ if $n=1\textrm{ mod }4$, $-1$ if $n=3\textrm{ mod }4$ and zero otherwise.

I'm looking for an exact value, if there is one, and a derivation.

Comment: I strongly doubt that this sum has a nice closed form.

Comment: You should know from the Euler product for $L(s,\chi)$ that there is never a closed-form for $\sum_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p}$, only for $\log L(1,\chi)=\sum_{p^k} \frac{\chi(p^k)}{k p^k}$ when $\chi(-1) = -1$ and for $\log L(2,\chi)$ when $\chi(-1)=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $|\chi(p)|\leq 1$, we may approximate $\frac{\chi(p)}{p}$ with $-\log\left(1-\frac{\chi(p)}{p}\right)$ and deduce that
$$ \sum_{p}\frac{\chi(p)}{p} \approx \log\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{\chi(p)}{p}\right)^{-1}=\log L(1)=\log\frac{\pi}{4} $$
where $L(s)$ stands for the Dirichlet $L$-function $L(s)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}$.
With the same mechanism leading to a series representation for the [prime $\zeta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function) (i.e. Moebius' inversion formula) we may state that

$$ \sum_{p}\frac{\chi(p)}{p} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\mu(n)\frac{\log L(n)}{n} $$
where the series on the RHS has a reasonable convergence speed, due to  $L(n)\approx 1-\frac{1}{3^n}\Rightarrow\log L(n)\approx -\frac{1}{3^n}$.
Numerically we have
$$ \sum_{p}\frac{\chi(p)}{p}\approx -0.18654766883298535284. $$

Comment: Then, it would seem that from a certain perspective, there are "slightly" more primes of the $4n + 3$ form than those of the $4n + 1$ form. Beautiful mystery!

Comment: @Piquito: the phenomenon has been deeply investigated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_bias

Comment: Every time in mathematics the expression "it has been deeply investigated" is used, that means that a large part of the human population is not invited to the party.

Comment: Well, I guess it is safe to say that a large part of the human population does not give a damn about Number Theory, so that is not utterly surprising.

Comment: However, I wanted to refer to the mathematical population of the world (my English is poor). Do not respond to this last comment. Regards